# C# - Embedding .swf file with parameters into WPF and make it look native?

Tags: c#, html, wpf, flash, embed

I have a shockwave flash file which needs some parameters to be passed to it ( I assume! ) because I'm not actually involved deeply in those stuff.

It looks like this when embedded into an HTML page :

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
<script language=JavaScript> var message="Function Disabled!"; function clickIE4(){ if (event.button==2){ return false; } } function clickNS4(e){ if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){ if (e.which==2||e.which==3){ return false; } } } if (document.layers){ document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN); document.onmousedown=clickNS4; } else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){ document.onmousedown=clickIE4; } document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false") </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<object id="RadioPlayer" width="406" height="150" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" name="RadioPlayer" align="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><param name="_cx" value="5080" /><param name="_cy" value="5080" /><param name="FlashVars" value="serverHost=www.krykey.com&amp;radio=24295&amp;listUrl=" /><param name="Movie" value="http://www.krykey.com/swf/player/RadioPlayer.swf" /><param name="Src" value="http://www.krykey.com/swf/player/RadioPlayer.swf" /><param name="WMode" value="Transparent" /><param name="Play" value="0" /><param name="Loop" value="-1" /><param name="Quality" value="High" /><param name="SAlign" value="LT" /><param name="Menu" value="-1" /><param name="Base" value="" /><param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" /><param name="Scale" value="NoScale" /><param name="DeviceFont" value="0" /><param name="EmbedMovie" value="0" /><param name="BGColor" value="FFFFFF" /><param name="SWRemote" value="" /><param name="MovieData" value="" /><param name="SeamlessTabbing" value="1" /><param name="Profile" value="0" /><param name="ProfileAddress" value="" /><param name="ProfilePort" value="0" /><param name="AllowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="AllowFullScreen" value="false" /><param name="src" value="http://www.krykey.com/swf/player/RadioPlayer.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="serverHost=www.krykey.com&amp;radio=24295&amp;listUrl=http://www.krykey.com" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="pluginspage" value="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="sameDomain" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="play" value="0" /><param name="loop" value="loop" /><param name="salign" value="LT" /><param name="menu" value="-1" /><param name="base" value="" /><param name="scale" value="NoScale" /><param name="devicefont" value="0" /><param name="embedmovie" value="0" /><param name="swremote" value="" /><param name="moviedata" value="" /><param name="seamlesstabbing" value="1" /><param name="profile" value="0" /><param name="profileaddress" value="" /><param name="profileport" value="0" /><param name="allownetworking" value="all" /><param name="allowfullscreen" value="false" /><embed id="RadioPlayer" width="406" height="150" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.krykey.com/swf/player/RadioPlayer.swf" _cx="5080" _cy="5080" FlashVars="serverHost=www.krykey.com&amp;radio=24295&amp;listUrl=" Movie="http://www.krykey.com/swf/player/RadioPlayer.swf" Src="http://www.krykey.com/swf/player/RadioPlayer.swf" WMode="Transparent" Play="0" Loop="-1" Quality="High" SAlign="LT" Menu="-1" Base="" AllowScriptAccess="sameDomain" Scale="NoScale" DeviceFont="0" EmbedMovie="0" BGColor="FFFFFF" SWRemote="" MovieData="" SeamlessTabbing="1" Profile="0" ProfileAddress="" ProfilePort="0" AllowNetworking="all" AllowFullScreen="false" flashvars="serverHost=www.krykey.com&amp;radio=24295&amp;listUrl=http://www.krykey.com" wmode="transparent" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" quality="high" play="0" loop="loop" salign="LT" menu="-1" base="" scale="NoScale" devicefont="0" embedmovie="0" swremote="" moviedata="" seamlesstabbing="1" profile="0" profileaddress="" profileport="0" allownetworking="all" allowfullscreen="false" name="RadioPlayer" align="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" /></object>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the "style.css" file :

```
#main {
position: fixed;
top: -20px;
left: 0px;
width: 416px;
height: 150px;
}
```

---

How can I embed that (swf page "or" html page) into my WPF application and make it look like if it was an original part of the WPF application itself ?

I don't want it to look like an external HTML page has been embedded only, it has to be as I mentioned above, so ..  any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this yet?

Comment: @user1842134 Not yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Web Browser element and put HTML.